# PHP, merge two arrays, remove the same values

Tags: php, mysql, merge

Is there a better way how to do it? Some one function in PHP?

```
  $a = array(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6);
  $b = array(1, 2, 8, 9, 10, 3, 20);

  $c = array_merge($a, $b);
  $c = array_unique($c);
```

Result: 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 8, 9, 10, 20

Or is there some way how to do it in MySQL? In case that:

```
$a = getMySQLArray("SELECT id FROM table1 WHERE ...")
$b = getMySQLArray("SELECT id FROM table2 WHERE ...")
```

I need to do two steps(two SELECT) to get all ids which I need but sometimes both array can contain the same id so I need to filter it. I'm not so expert with SQL to create some more complex SQL request. It is possible to create something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a single query to get those distinct values with [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/union.html):

```
SELECT 
    id 
FROM table1 WHERE ...
UNION
SELECT 
    id 
FROM table2 WHERE ...
```

`UNION` without the keyword `ALL` will only return distinct rows, in your case distinct values.

```
SELECT ...
UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...
[UNION [ALL | DISTINCT] SELECT ...]
```

> UNION is used to combine the result from multiple SELECT statements
> into a single result set.
> ...
>
> The default behavior for UNION is that duplicate rows are removed from the result.